# Facebook api graph doesn't return me all the feeds

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The graph api (feed) isn't showing me all what I need. I mean like when I did a post here, I got an alert on realtime updates (object: user, fields: feed) but when I sending request to graph api with my id and my access token I just not able to see it. It the same for when I do likes to people pictures / statues etc..

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffeed

Answer (score 1):

Lint the access token and ensure you have read_stream permissions on it.

Comment: I do have the read_stream permission in fact I have all the permissions that available

Comment: Try looking on `me/home` instead of `me/feed`  to see if it is there instead.

Comment: nad it's not on `/me/feed` either?  How about on `/me/statuses` ?